# How to stop entire script from running when certain condition met without error in R

Tags: r

```
i=14
l=8
if(i>l){q()}

print(i)
print(l)
```

above code is what I simplfied and when I run code above, it ends up with " R session aborted. R encountered a fatal error"

pls advise me way to avoid this error

Comment: How are you running this? If I stick it in a file called `wut.R` and do `R CMD BATCH wut.R` then I don't get an abort/fatal error. What operating system? What R environment?

Comment: In any case you probably want `break` , not `q`

Comment: Or `stop()`. Any more clues, Jae?

Comment: Hi I run this code in Rstudio on Window8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `q()` inside an `if` block from a script in the editor pane of RStudio crashes my RStudio in a similar manner, with a fatal error dialog box. I suspect this is an RStudio bug and should be reported if it recurs with the latest RStudio.

Just putting `q()` in a script *not* in an `if` block quits RStudio as expected, without error messages.

The correct way to terminate a script without killing R in any way is to use `stop("why")`.

```
if(1>0)stop("am stopping")
print("No")
```